# Validation Rule not working when numbers are added

Tags: validation-rule

```
OR(
CONTAINS("Post Office Box:P.O. Box:PO Box:Post Box:Box:P O Box", ShippingStreet )
)
```

The validation fires when we enter PO Box / Post Office Box / Post Box, but when it is entered with other text like PO Box 123456, East Ham, London. The validation rule is not working.

But as per the condition when Shipping Street contains PO Box, the rule must be fired, but it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Salesforce help/documentation does not longer clearly describe this usage of the CONTAINS function. But the old version used to contain this example:

> Example 2: a. CONTAINS("CA:NV:FL:NY",BillingState) Will return TRUE if
> BillingState is CA,NV,V,L,FL:NY or any exact match of "CA:NV:FL:NY".
> **NOTE: when using contains with the multiple operator (:) contains then
> becomes equals.**

So I'm afraid what you want to achieve is not going to work. You will have to split out into multiple CONTAINS functions (one for each way of writing PO Box).

```
OR(
CONTAINS(ShippingStreet,"Post Office Box" )
,
CONTAINS(ShippingStreet,"P.O. Box" )
,
CONTAINS(ShippingStreet,"PO Box" )
,
CONTAINS(ShippingStreet,"Post Box" )
,
CONTAINS(ShippingStreet, "P O Box")
)
```

Alternatively, since you're checking for purely 'Box' as well, you could just as well do that check only.. All the other search terms also contain 'Box'....

```
CONTAINS(ShippingStreet,"Box" )
```

There you have the risk, of course, that there is a false positive for "Box Street" etc..